# Write a program in C that reads up to 100 integers from a file, where the first value from the file is the number of subsequent values in the file

Tags: c, file-io

Write code that reads a number of values, interpreted as integers, from a file named “mtData.txt”, where the first number tells how many subsequent numbers there are, and there will never be more than 100 integers.
I'm new to C, coming from a background in Java. I wrote the following, producing an infinite loop that prints the obvious statements and an address not the values from the file.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int main(){

    FILE *fp = (FILE*) 0;
    int c = -1;

    fp = fopen("myInput.txt", "r");

    if(fp == NULL){
        puts("Error accessing file");
        return(-1);
    }
        bool doneReading = false;
        int numbers[100];
        while (!doneReading){
            puts("Reading now");
            c = fscanf(fp, "%d", numbers);
            printf("Read %d items\n", c);
            if(feof(fp)){
                doneReading = true;
            }
            printf("%d\n", numbers);

    fclose(fp);
}
}
```

Comment: You should read the first value (the number of subsequent values), before entering a loop controlled by that value. You don't need `doneReading` or `feof()` but if `c != 1` that's a data error you can't recover from.

Comment: Start by fixing the indention so that the code is readable.

Comment: Hangry, Aside: Instead of `FILE *fp = (FILE*) 0;`, consider dropping the unneeded cast or even better: `FILE *fp = fopen("myInput.txt", "r");`  [RAII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_acquisition_is_initialization).

Answer (score 1):

A possible approach (take a look at how the loop is implemented):

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int main(void) {
    FILE* fp = fopen("myInput.txt", "r");

    if (fp == NULL) {
        puts("Error accessing file");
        return 1;
    }

    // this is the array that will contain the numbers
    int numbers[100];
    // this is the number of integers that the file contains
    int max_numbers;
    // this is the number of integers that we have actually read from the file
    int counter = 0;

    // max_numbers is actually the first integer that we find in the file
    if (fscanf(fp, "%d", &max_numbers) != 1 || max_numbers < 0 || max_numbers > 100) {
        printf("ERROR\n");
        return 1;
    }

    printf("Max numbers: %d\n", max_numbers);

    // now that we know the number of integers, we can loop to read them all
    while (counter < max_numbers) {
        if (fscanf(fp, "%d", &numbers[counter]) != 1) {
            printf("ERROR\n");
            return 1;
        }

        counter += 1;
    }

    // now we print all the numbers that we have read
    for (int i = 0; i < counter; i += 1) {
        printf("Number #%d = %d\n", i, numbers[i]);
    }

    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

I used `fscanf(fp, "%d", &var) != 1` to put the number inside `var` and check that everything went well (`fscanf()` will return the number of arguments successfully assigned, in this case only `%d`).

---

EDIT:

The previous code does not check if the file contains more data than necessary (that would also mean that the file is not valid), so it just ignores that extra data (thanks @chux for pointing it out).

Also note that `fscanf()` will not detect integer overflows, so in the future you may want to look at alternative approaches for integer parsing (e.g.: `strtol()`).

Comment: That makes much more sense. Thank you so much!

Comment: Good answer with good error checks (minor: missing detection of too much data).

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Thanks for pointing it out (missing detection of too much data). It seemed too much for a homework assignment question, but I forgot to even mention it (I've edited the question accordingly). For what is worth, `fscanf()` is also a poor choice here for me (missing detection of integer overflow), but as I said, for homework it's fine I guess.